# What type is this compressed air/pneumatic connector?

Tags: maintenance, tools, pressure, tool-identification

I need to build an adapter for this connector, however, I wasn't able to identify it. I measured it with a digital caliper. It doesn't seem to be a common connector, at least in Germany.

Can you identify this connector? I have two adapters that use this connector, a brake bleeder and a coolant leak tester.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it unscrew? If so do that and make an adapter for the threaded hole instead.

Comment: Does not appear to be a standard german quick coupler>>>>http://www.air-pneumatic-fittings.com/Europe%20Type%20Quick%20Couplers/Europe-Type-Quick-Couplers-German-type.html

Comment: I also had that idea & tried to unscrew it, but it's too tight, probably glued in for sealing. It's also not my adapter, so I don't want to mess it up or modify it.

Comment: Its probably a custom coupler manufactured by the company that made the tool.

Comment: Its a pipe thread so it will be tight, I would use an air impact wrench to remove it but understand it is not yours.

Comment: I contacted the company but never got a reply. It's part of a Laser Tools 4832 brake bleeder btw. [This part](https://www.lasertools.co.uk/PIS/5700_PIS.pdf) appears to be compatible, but has a different looking connector. From the link you posted earlier, it looks like a Japan type connector.

Comment: Use a ring spanner - a long one not a short stubby cheap one.

Comment: @theluckyluke i cannot find an exact match for that style, must be custom manufactured.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this connector type, so I "sacrificed" the coolant adapter to build an adapter. Now I can either use the brake bleeder with this proprietary connector or use a standard (NW 7,2) connector.

I'll attach a cheap schrader valve to the coolant adapter, so it's still usable for me.